# Call to a member function prepare() on a non-object (Working on website but not WAMP/XAMPP)

Tags: php, function, member

So I have been working on a website with a friend of mine for a while and I have hit this issue on my local wamp server where I have been previewing my work, despite it working previously it has begun spiting a variety of errors that where not there before, I have updated my wamp, reinstalled tried xampp and get the same error. This has been holding on for a while so help is appreciated as always.

AGAIN THIS WORKS ON MY FRIENDS TEST ENVIRONMENT AND THE SERVER EVEN THOUGH THE FILES ARE ALL IDENTICAL

from this code

```
<?php
class navigation extends connector {

public function getNav() {
    $con = $this->connect();

    $query = $con->prepare('SELECT * FROM navigation ORDER BY position ASC');
    $query->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    $query->execute();
    echo "<nav><ul>";
    while ($row = $query->fetch()) {
        if(!empty($_SESSION['user'])) {
            if($_SESSION['user']['permission'] >= $row['read'] && $row['position'] > 0) {
                echo "<li><a href=" . $row['url'] . ">" . $row['text'] . "</a></li>";
            }
        }
        else {
            if($row['read'] == 0) {
                echo "<li><a href=" . $row['url'] . ">" . $row['text'] . "</a></li>";
            }
        }
    };
    echo "</ul></nav>";
    unset($con);
}
};
?>
```

I get

> "Fatal error: Call to a member function prepare() on a non-object in
>   E:\wamp\www\UKSFSITE\php\classes\class_navigation.php on line 7"

this worked before but not now ?!!? any thoughts

Thanks again

Comment: You don't check $con for being a valid connection - I am quite sure, it isn't

Comment: Beautiful damn person, I took the files from the site so the connect class was set wrong something silly I had forgotten but had me pinned for a week thanks!

Comment: Happy to have helped!

Comment: sometimes an extra pair of eyes help :)

Answer (score 0):

you should check if $con is an object. if its not then check why its not connected. could be problem with name resolution or your network not stable.